# Problem with \usepackage[final]{graphicx} in combination with \documentclass[man]{apa6}

Tags: captions

I use

```
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

in combination with

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
```

and then I obtain an error message.

In combination with

```
\documentclass{article}
```

there is no problem. However, I have to use

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `apa6` class loads `graphicx` (for no apparent reason), but provides no way for adding options to it.

On the other hand, I see no problem with graphic inclusions if I remove the top line.

You can do as follows, if you need the `draft` class option:

```
\documentclass[man,draft]{apa6}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
```

Comment: Latex has still problems with \usepackage{subcaption}

Comment: @AdvanderVen What problems?

Comment: The Latex source file underneath works:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[final]{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}

The Latex source file underneath ddoes not work:

\documentclass[man,draft]{apa6}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}

\usepackage[final]{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}


Compilation yields:

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.
                
                                                  
l.5 \usepackage
               {subcaption}
?

Comment: @AdvanderVen Remove `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}`.

Comment: Dear egreg, Please send me an e-mail and I will send my Latex source files to you with my questions. My e-mail address is a.vanderven@pwo.ru.nl Thanks.

Comment: @AdvanderVen Sorry, but this is out of the question.

Comment: Hi egreg, 

Oké. 

In the mean time I have solved the problem.

With

\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}

one obtains  1 error: 

! Undefined control sequence.

<argument> \@shorttitle                         

l.104 \efloatseparator

You can simply solve the problem by clicking on Enter.